How to properly load data into a ComboBox in Django with m3_ext and objectpack?
I am developing a Django application using m3_ext and objectpack for the UI components. I need to load ContentType objects into a ComboBox directly from the database. However, my current implementation is not working as expected. The combo box does not show the ContentType of an existing record when editing. You still can choose from combo box, but i really need existing value shoving in combo box for editing.
from objectpack.actions import ObjectPack
from objectpack.ui import ModelEditWindow, BaseEditWindow, make_combo_box
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, Group, User
from m3_ext.ui import all_components as ext

class ContentTypePack(ObjectPack):
    model = ContentType
    add_to_desktop = True
    add_window = edit_window = ModelEditWindow.fabricate(ContentType)

class PermissionEditWindow(BaseEditWindow):

    def _init_components(self):
        super(PermissionEditWindow, self)._init_components()

        self.field__name = ext.ExtStringField(
            label='Name',
            name='name',
            allow_blank=False,
            anchor='100%')

        self.field__content_type = make_combo_box(
            label='Content Type',
            name='ContentType',
            allow_blank=False,
            anchor='100%',
            data=[(ct.id, ct.model) for ct in ContentType.objects.all()])

        self.field__codename = ext.ExtStringField(
            label='Codename',
            name='codename',
            allow_blank=False,
            anchor='100%')

    def _do_layout(self):
        super(PermissionEditWindow, self)._do_layout()
        self.form.items.extend((
            self.field__name,
            self.field__content_type,
            self.field__codename,
        ))

    def set_params(self, params):
        super(PermissionEditWindow, self).set_params(params)
        self.height = 'auto'

class PermissionPack(ObjectPack):
    model = Permission
    add_to_desktop = True
    add_window = edit_window = PermissionEditWindow

    def save_row(self, obj, create_new, request, context):
        obj.name = request.POST.get('name')
        content_type_id = request.POST.get('ContentType')
        if content_type_id:
            obj.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(pk=content_type_id)
        obj.codename = request.POST.get('codename')
        obj.save()
        return obj

In edit window content type is empty
I've already tried changing the name line from ‘ContentType’ to ‘content_type’ and after that it does show in the combo box what ContentType is currently assigned, but an error pops up when trying to save the record. I expect the Permission record edit box to inherit the ContentType value with the ability to select the ContentType from the combo box
Existing ContentType
Error
